# Input data from table of arrays into list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list

I've got a list and I want to input a data from it by the table of arrays and I don't have idea how .
Here is the code and my attempts:

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div class="top-menu style4"style="margin-top:300px;">
    <ul class="top-menu-main">
      <li>
    <ul class="top-submenu">
      <li><a  class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">SEMINARS</a></li>
      <li><a  class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">STATUTES</a></li>
      <li><a  class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">R&Eacute;SUM&Eacute;</a></li>
      <li><a  class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">ADR & PPCs</a></li>
      <li><a class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">PREPARATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a  class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">MUSINGS</a></li>
      <li><a  class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">GLOSSARY</a></li>
      <li><a class="up_items"style="padding-top:5px;">AWARDS</a></li>
    </ul>
        <a style="width:100px;text-align:center;text-align:center;font-family:arial;font-size:0.7em;font-weight:bold;border-top:none;">START</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried to do something with this script but what i got is a simple list without any slide, css elements and so on which i included in my code ..

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeMenu() {
  var items = ['Start','Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','5','5'];
  var str = '<ul><li>';
      str += items.join('</li><li>');
      str += '</li></ul>';
  document.getElementById('jMenu0').innerHTML = str;
}
window.onload = function() { makeMenu(); }


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jMenu").jMenu();
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.

Use the same jQuery ready function to load menu.
Use .class selector or #id to select the menu.
Don't include two times the UL tag.

Here is your code working:

```
function makeMenu() {
  var items = ['Start','Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','5','5'];
  var str = '<li>';
      str += items.join('</li><li>');
      str += '</li>';
      $('.top-menu-main').html(str);
}


  $(document).ready(function(){
    makeMenu();
    $(".top-menu-main").menu();
  });
```

You can check it here:

http://jsbin.com/irasof/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, it helped but id, in my case should be in [code]<ul class="top-submenu">[code] section and i have to add <a> next to <li> :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned an `id` to your unordered list.

the call

```
$("#jMenu").jMenu();
```

expects to find an element with the id `jMenu`.

Try adding that id in your js function

```
var str = '<ul id\"jMenu\"><li>';
```

take a look at the docs of that [plug-in](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jmenu)

And the line

```
document.getElementById('jMenu0').innerHTML = str;
```

tries to add the generated HTML inside an element with the id `jMenu0`. The HTML code you are showing does not contain such an element. You need to add it first, maybe somthing like that will be enough

```
<div id="jMenu0" />
```